# Is google being paranoid?

Tags: php, security, validation

[On this page about hashbangs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot) I saw the following:

```
// get the _escaped_fragment_ parameter
$escapedfragment = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'];
// NOTE: VALIDATE PARAMETERS (as always, to avoid security risks)
$params = getParams($unescapedfragment);
```

What is the point of doing this? It's all server side and it's not a risk on sql injection or PHP evaling.

Why bother validating? What possible `$_GET['_escaped_fragment_']` can be a problem

Comment: That depends on how that data is used

Comment: This is the choice of the programmer who wrote the code. It does not mean it's the best way to go.

Comment: first rule about security, sanitize everything that comes from client. Paranoia is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the PHP being executed is used to generate dynamic content for the search engines to index. It'll need to generate the same content that your users will see when they're interacting with the site -- and for that, it might need to retrieve files off the filesystem, execute database queries, connect to remote systems, etc.

The advice is definitely well-placed. This is a second mechanism to run script content on your server, and if you blindly run the same things without performing input validation here, perhaps the crawler will inadvertently knock off a security problem -- or provide attackers a second route to your data.